# High Charts : Two lines showing instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, frontend

I,m working with highcharts.js

The issue is while creating a graph its showing me two lines instead of
one.

**It should only show me one line** because its ploting the graph between 2 values
which are (timestamp and value).

Can you please check why its showing me two lines instead of one and how can i fix this :

(Just copy and paste the code in a file and it should work).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="background:#212224;">

<div id="container" style="max-width: 1666px;  margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.getJSON('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76618626/data4.json', function (data) {
        console.log("data size is : ");
        console.log(data);      

        var data3 = [];

                    $.each(data.data,function(i,d){
                    console.log(new Date(d.timestamp).getTime(), d.value);

                        data3.push([new Date(d.timestamp).getTime(),d.value]);

                    });

                    console.log("Data 3 is :");
                    console.log(data3);
                    var data4 = [];
                    Highcharts.each(data3, function(p, i) {
                        if (typeof p[0] !== 'number' || typeof p[1] !== 'number') {
                             console.log('Invalid data is :')
                             console.log(p);
                        } else {
                            data4.push(p);
                        }
                    });



        $('#container').highcharts({

            chart: {
            backgroundColor: '#000000',
                },

            title: {
                text: 'Test Graph',
                style: {
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                title: {
                    text: 'Time Stamp'
                },
                gridLineColor: 'grey',
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                lineWidth:1

            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                gridLineColor: 'grey',
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                lineWidth:1
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },

            exporting: false,



            plotOptions: {
                line: {                 
                    lineColor: 'red',
                    fillOpacity: 1,                    
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 2
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null,
                    marker: {
                        fillColor: '#e57255'
                        }


                },


            },


            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                name: 'test',
                data: data4
            }]
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok....i,ve sort of found the issue here....the data coming from JSON is weird...the value of the timestamps goes back....after 6th july...its giving me previous dates like 4th of july....is there a way to sort the data with respect to the timestamp dates....?

Comment: The data is round over again. It could be, there should be 2 lines, you pick either series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/zxsfxzag/18/). It is actually a single Line chart.

Check out the print out at `console.log(new Date(d.timestamp).toString(), d.value);`.

Your data's timestamps start from `Tue Jul 05 2016 03:00:00`, increase to `Thu Jul 07 2016 03:00:00`, and starts again from `Jul 05 2016 03:00:00`.

Hence this is why your chart seems like a two-line chart. The bottom part of the line is being linked back to the top line.

Just update your data JSON and you will be good.

**Edited**:

Update my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/zxsfxzag/20/) to arrange timestamps using `.sort()`.

Comment: I don't want to update data....is there a way to sort the data with respect to the timestamps ? I,ve created an array of data4 if you see my code...is there a way we can sort the array of data3 and place it in data4 ?

Comment: @Simon Updated my answer to sort timestamp.

Comment: Thanks Wilts....the graph looks really weird now after sorting...lol.
Are you sure everything is working perfectly...(just a thought).

Comment: @Simon The data is sorted accordingly based on timestamp only. Value is not sorted for your information. Check my console.log() for prove.